# Gerrit ssh users on EC2/ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, gerrit

I'm trying to deploy gerrit code review to AWS and am running into problems with trying to ssh in once it's deployed.  When I've created a new user, what *does* work is SSH tunneling in like

```
ssh -fNL 29418:<ec2-host>:29418 ec2-user@<ec2-host>
```

then ssh'ing locally with the gerrit username.  If, however, I try just running ssh directly like:

```
ssh -p 29418 <gerrit user>@<ec2-host>
```

I get `ssh_exchange_identification: read: Operation timed out`

I've also tried deploying using the official docker image on ecs, with the same result.  What I take this to mean is that gerrit is not able to make user accounts that are local to the host machine.  The question, then, is how do new user accounts get ssh access?  Is it a problem with gerrit configuration or with the AWS settings?  None of the tutorials I found mentioned further steps.

I've been trying with gerrit 2.15.3

Answer (score 0):

Well, funny story.  Organizational firewalls can suck sometimes.  Really, really suck.  Like, "we're gonna open up 8080 but not 29418" suck.

Org firewall was preventing inbound traffic on 29418 so the handshake couldn't finish.  Can either tunnel or change gerrit's port.